# c++ MakeFile linking to SQlite library

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm new to C++.

I have been given Makefile for a program. I want to add the SQLite library to it. I downloaded the source code from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

I'm just wondering what do I put in the Makefile so that it is able to find it. I've been reading up about Makefiles, should I use a CXXFLAG?

Comment: Do you need to build sqlite from source? Or just link against a system provided sqlite library? The latter just requires adding the right flags (possibly to `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` but it depends on the makefile).

Comment: This question is too broad, as you don't seem to know what a Makefile really is. Generally, there's no single answer to your question, because it depends on the Makefile itself.

Comment: You better download it using your package manager or at least use the prebuilt libraries from that site, compiling it from source is extra burden. Then adding `-lsqlite3` to your link flags should suffice.

Comment: And `CXXFLAG` is for compiler flags, usually. There should be a different variable for libraries, giving a snippet of your Makefile might help.

Comment: please share your Makefile. You need to add sqlite.h to compiled files.

Comment: Hi, I added my Makefile, the Makefile cross compiles for another platform. The other platform as SQLite installed. I just want to copy the executable and shared library over to the platform. Thanks

Comment: On a sane system, `CFLAGS+=$(pkg-config --cflags sqlite3)` and `LDLIBS+=$(pkg-config --libs sqlite3)` should be sufficient.  On an insane system, well, it's anybody's guess.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to link with SQLite is to use it's amalgamation file: https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html

You just add it to your sources and compile as part of your project.